# Array sort misplaces the parameters of array objects - Flutter/Dart

Tags: arrays, sorting, dart, flutter

I'm fairly new to flutter and I'm building a list that sorts itself according to the usage of it's elements. But the problem is the sort method misplaces some parameters of array objects.

Here is the code I've tried,
later I've tried manually sorting as well but the result was same.
And when I comment only the array.sort part the code works without any issues.

Thank you in advance !

```
class _ListViewBuilderState extends State<ListViewBuilder> {
  List<Emoticon> _displayList = emoticonsList;

  Widget _buildListView() {
      _displayList.sort((b, a) => a.count.compareTo(b.count));

    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      itemCount: _displayList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return _buildRow(emoticonsList[_displayList[i].id]);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(Emoticon emo) {
    printEmoji(emo.id);

    return ListTile(
        title: Text(emo.emoji),
        trailing: Icon(
          emo.favorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
          color: emo.favorite ? Colors.red : null,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          emo.count++;
          printEmoji(emo.id);
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          setState(() {
            emo.favorite = !emo.favorite;
            printEmoji(emo.id);
          });
        });
  }
```

```
class Emoticon {
  final String emoji;
  final List<String> tags;
  int count = 0;
  final int id;
  bool favorite = false;

  Emoticon(this.id, this.emoji, this.tags);
}
```

```
final emoticonsList = [
  new Emoticon(0, "¯\_(ツ)_/¯", ["Other"]),
  new Emoticon(1, "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)", ["Happy"]),
  new Emoticon(2, "ಠ_ಠ", ["Sad"]),
  new Emoticon(3, "(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻", ["Sad", "Other"]),
  new Emoticon(4, "┬──┬◡ﾉ(° -°ﾉ)", ["Other"]),
  new Emoticon(5, "ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ", ["Happy"]),
];

void printEmoji(int i){
  print(
    emoticonsList[i].id.toString() + " " + 
    emoticonsList[i].favorite.toString() + " " + 
    emoticonsList[i].count.toString() + " " + 
    emoticonsList[i].emoji.toString()
  );
}
```

But when I run the code,

01 - Count values for each tile misplaces with each other

02 - tapping a list tile is printing another emoji than I tapped. And increment of count won't happen as well.

This is my first Stack Overflow question. SO I'm not sure if this info are enough. Please ask if any more information is needed.

Again thanks for helping !

Comment: Do you mean the used one will appear in start ?

Comment: No. The count parameters of the array items kind of exchange. I used shared preferences to store the values. so they have values in the beginning. But when the app starts those values exchange with each other. I checked but the problem lies in the sort method. And also when tapped on a tile, it prints another emoji. I can't seem to find why ?